# please guide me to split the image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to split an image in three parts, here is what I tried :

```matlab
[filename pathname]=uigetfile('*.png','Pick the image file');
file=strcat(pathname,filename);
I=imread(file);
figure,imshow(I);
title('Input Image');
im1=I;
su=median(im1);
median=ceil(su);
[row, col]=size(I);
%mr = median(row/2); % median of rows
mc = median(col/3); % median of columns
right = I(1:mr  , (mc+1):col);
figure,imshow(right)
```

I expected this to split the image into three parts but it is splitted into top right and left and creating mirror image

This is the image which I need to split into three parts, but it should be single image:

[image: example image]

Comment: When you do `median=ceil(su);` you overwrite the `median` function, making it no longer accessible. You should not do this. If you run your script the second time it will do something different than it did the first time. Find a different name!

Comment: i have removed median=ceil(su); this command and then worked still i am getting error.. Please help..  how to split the image into three parts i am not getting any idea. i want to split the image of blood samples

Comment: I was not intending for my comment to answer your question, it was just an aside, hoping to help you with good practices. Regarding this image: you want to split each of these three samples? How consistently are they placed in the image? Are all images in the series very consistent, or would the split have to be computed from the image contents? What do you mean with "but it should be single image"?

Comment: all the images in series.... i want to split the image into three parts..not single image...!!! i want to calculate the area and mean for a particular drop of blood from the three drops of blood like coagulated one and non coagulated one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to split the image into as many splits as you want:

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4wAt.png');
[h w c] = size(img);
numSplits = 3;  % how many splits you want
sw = floor(w/numSplits);  % width of split 
widths = repmat(sw, 1, numSplits-1);
widths(numSplits) = w - sum(widths);  % last one is bit wider if width does not divide
splits = mat2cell(img, h, widths, c);  % this splits the image

% show the splits
for ii=1:numSplits 
   subplot(1,numSplits,ii);
   imshow(splits{ii});
end
```

Results with
[image]

Comment: i need to convert the splitted image into gary colour image so how can i convert that image. This is my code...but i am getting error. im2=image(splits{ii});

imshow(im2);

% %% Gray Conversion

a=rgb2gray(im2);
figure,imshow(a);
title('Gray conversion Image');

Comment: @StellaJoseph please post it as a new question

Comment: Can you guide me to split this image into separate 3 images